# How to find whether a string has repeated characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this code ...and the answer I am expecting is not correct
in this code, if a string has repeated characters, it should return False
but its returning True in all cases

I have done this much coding to try to solve this problem
This is in JUPYTER notebook

```
def is_isogram(string):
   for i in string:
       if string.count(i) == 1:
           print('True')
       elif string.count(i) > 1:
           print('False')
```

I typed 'Hello' it should return False, but returnung true in all cases

Comment: You can only determine if it's true once you've checked whether *all* letters only appear once.

Comment: i mean, the code here doesn't return anything, and prints a bunch of True and False because you're asking it to print on every character instead of finishing up with the entire string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing `True` and `False` for each character in the string. Running your code with input "hello" will give 5 lines of output, two `True`, two `False` and one more `True`.

```py
def is_isogram(string):
   for i in string:
       if string.count(i) > 1:
           return False
   return True
```

This code will return either True or False. If any character in the string appears more than once, the function returns False and exits. If none of the characters appear more than once, it returns True after exiting the loop.

#### Explanation of the code

You can be sure that the word is not an isogram if any letter appears more than once, ie, you don't have to traverse the whole string, just until you find a repeated character. But to be sure that you have an isogram, you need to check the whole string.

`for i in string:`

This statement iterates through the loop character by character.

```py
    if string.count(i) > 1:
        return False
```

The if statement checks if the current character, i, appears more than once in the string. If it does, the function returns `False`. If not, it continues to the next iteration.

```
    return True
```

If the control has reached this statement, it means that none of the characters appear twice, as the function would have returned `False` before reaching this statement. So, the function returns `True`

Example

Consider the input `"hello"`.
Iteration 1: `i = 'h'` and `string.count('h') = 1`
So, do nothing
Iteration 2: `i = 'e'` and `string.count('e') = 1`
So, do nothing
Iteration 3: `i = 'l'` and `string.count('l') = 2`
So, return `False`.
If you called the function like, `print(is_isogram("hello"))`, `False` will be printed.

Consider another input `"abcd"`
Iteration 1: `i = 'a'` and `string.count('a') = 1`
So, do nothing
Iteration 2: `i = 'b'` and `string.count('b') = 1`
So, do nothing
Iteration 3: `i = 'c'` and `string.count('c') = 1`
So, do nothing
Iteration 4: `i = 'd'` and `string.count('d') = 1`
So, do nothing

At this point, the loop is exhausted and the `return True` statement is executed

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the code you have written??

Comment: Thank you so much!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can be sure that your word isn't an isogram as soon as you find a count greater than one, but you can only be sure that it is one once you have checked all letters:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    for i in string:
        if string.count(i) > 1:
            return False
    return True

print(is_isogram('pear'))
#  True

print(is_isogram('apple'))
# False
```

Or, if you really want your function to print its output instead of returning it, which I would generally not recommend:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    for i in string:
        if string.count(i) > 1:
            print('False')
            return
    print('True')
```

A shorter, classic solution would be to make a `set` of characters, and to check if the number of unique characters is equal to the length of the string

```
def is_isogram2(string):
    return len(set(string)) == len(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple snippet you can use to check if the string has repeated characters. Iterate through all the characters and check if it has already come before.

```
def is_isogram(s):
    mp = {}
    for c in s:
        if c in mp.keys():
            return False
        mp[c] = 1 
    return True
```

Comment: Yes you are right . I said it as due to the string module which is not used here. Editing my answer .

Answer (score 0):

Not very pythonic, but in your original style:

```
def is_isogram(s):
    for i in s:
        if s.count(i) > 1:
            return False
    return True
```